# Given K polygons, with total n edges, find a point covered by max amount of polygons

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given K polygons, with total n edges, how can I find a point covered by maximum amount of polygons?

I belive there must be a way to do it with LP, but i was not able to define the equations.

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can find all intersections among n line segments in time O((n+m) log n) by Bentley & Ottman [m being the number of intersections found] or O(n log n + m) by Chazelle & Edelsrunner. The first is practical. I guess that you can enhance it by an accounting of polygon overlaps (along the sweepline, you count the points as entering or exiting from their polygon, so as to maintain the number of overlappings.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust any attempts to do it with sleep line algorithm failed so far.

Comment: Try with sweep-line then.